# Beaglebone black running Debian: "E: unable to locate package"

Tags: linux, debian, beaglebone

So I've recently started trying to teach myself embedded linux using a beaglebone. I am relatively new to this, so bear with me please. I am having trouble with an error that I first encountered when trying to install ntp:

> E: Unable to locate package ntp

I tried for a couple of other installs, like gedit, and had the same issue. I have already tried

> sudo apt-get update

but that does not work either. I am thinking it has something to do with my default directories being set up incorrectly. My root directory was empty when I first started. This is my linux version:

> Linux beaglebone 4.14.71-ti-r80 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Oct 5 23:50:11 UTC 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

Thanks in advance to anyone who is able to help.

Comment: Do you have internet connection?

Comment: Yes. Although it really slow. Could excessively slow interenet (in the range of 200-400 kbps) cause this type of issue?

Comment: Maybe. It can timeout when contacting the server.